# Border Styles for the Highchart tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to edit the border for my tooltip in highcharts.

The problem I am having is I would like to have only the bottom border show up.

For example you can do something like this:

tooltip: {borderWidth: 10} // but the problem is makes a border around the entire tooltip

doing something like this would be nice, but doesn't seem possible:

tooltip: {borderWidth:  0, 0, 0, 10}

I have tried this as well:

tooltip: {style: {border-bottom:10}}

But that doesn't seem to work as well.
I am beginning to wonder if this is even possible.

OR

Does anyone know a good site that shows what specifically is allowed in the style attribute for tooltip. Seems like there is a certain way to do styles in this attribute, but http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip doesn't really give you enough information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply use an HTML tooltip in Highcharts by setting `useHTML: true`; see example: http://jsfiddle.net/xq28t/

In JS:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    borderWidth: 0,
    style: {
        padding: 0
    }
},
```

In CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but how do you get it to use the default color? (the color of the item it is hovering over.)

Comment: It's not possible without using formatter. In formatter you can use html tags, and there you can set series.color for inline CSS.